# Regex: selecting between quotation marks with positive lookbehind

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to extract data between quotation marks in the following text:

```
msgid: "something"
msgidd: "something"
msgid:"something"
msgidd:"something"
msgid:      "something"
msgidd:      "something"
```

With `(?<=msgsid:.{1}?)(.+[^"]")` I get what follows after `msgid:` but not always what's inside the quotation marks. My goal is to replace what's inside the quotation marks yet keep `msgid:` intact. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using lookbehind makes it a lot more difficult as the matching allowed is much more limited. It's easier to do:

```
(msgid+:\s*)"(.*?)"
```

And do the replacement as `$1"something-replacement"`

Comment: Thanks. Your example works but it wipes out "msgid:" when I replace $1 with something else.

Comment: Oh OK, I edited it now for that. Can you see if it works now?

Comment: It does, thank you. I guess with lookbehind things can get pretty messy.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a lookbehind? Try this:

```
msgid:\s*"([^"]+)"
```

And test it here at [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/p8bHMYp6m1) or [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=7c15c92f-65b7-43d4-a639-d45518bba494).

**Update**:
For the replace, try the below and test it [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=f50db34d-cbbf-4750-898f-b3f586aa3aed)

Regex:

`(msgid:\s*")[^"]+(")`

Replacement:

`$1replacementstring$2`

Source:

```
msgid: "something"
msgidd: "something"
msgid:"something"
msgidd:"something"
msgid:      "something"
msgidd:      "something"
```

Final String:

```
msgid: "replacementstring"
msgidd: "something"
msgid:"replacementstring"
msgidd:"something"
msgid:      "replacementstring"
msgidd:      "something"
```

---

Anyway, if this is a challenge that you need to use a lookbehind, then use the below only to match. But it would not make sense to use this in your replace.

```
(?<=msgid:)\s*"([^"]+)"
```

Comment: Because when I do a replace, I want to keep "msgid:" (with all possible spaces after it) intact and change only what's inside the quotation marks.

Your first example works but it wipes out "msgid:". Second example with lookbehind doesn't match anything.

Comment: Regarding the lookbehind, where are you trying to match this? Notepad++?

Comment: GSkinner is perl based regex engine hence does not allow quantifiers in lookbehinds. Perl limits lookbehind to constant-width expressions. I have modified the regex to capture the `something`s.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware about quantifiers in lookbehinds.

Answer (score 1):

I heartily agree that you shouldn't use lookbehind if you don't have to, but that isn't what's causing your problem.  This is the culprit: `.{1}?`.  You probably meant for it to match an optional sixth letter like the second `d` in some of your inputs.  That would be simply `.?`, but most regex flavors will reject that because of the constant-width requirement.

What `.{1}?` really means is *match exactly one character, non-greedily*, which is kinda pointless, but it's syntactically valid.  I tested it in several flavors, half expecting them to reject it anyway, but they all matched `.{1}?` as if it were just `.`.  As for `.?`, there are a few flavors (like .NET and Java) that will match it as you intended, and there are workarounds you can use in the other flavors, but in most cases the best solution is simply not to use lookbehind.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Actually, that `.{1}?` was meant to match anything that follows after `msgid:` (e.g., `msgid:"something"` and `msgid:      "something"`)